# Map several variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

At the time i produce output with this code:

```
     <h3>
     <% @partner.employees.each do |s| %>
       <%= "#{s.forename} #{s.lastname} " %>
     <% end %>
     <%= " ..." %></h3>
```

This for example produces this output:

```
    Josef Smith Daniel Crak ....
```

My problem is that i try to get this output:

```
    Josef Smith, Daniel Crak ....
```

I tried something like that:

```
    @partner.employees.all.map(:forname, :lastname)
```

But this produced this error:

```
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

I hope somebody can help me find a short solution! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like

`@partner.employees.map { |s| "#{s.forename} #{s.lastname} " }.join(',')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way :

```
<% @partner.employees.each do |s| %>
       <%= %i(forename lastname).map{|m| s.send(m)}.join(" ") + "," %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, here's what's going on.

`map` takes just one parameter, a block. You can use a symbol prepended by an ampersand as a shorthand for that if you just need to call one method that has no arguments, e.g.

```
@partner.employees.map(&:firstname)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
@partner.employees.map { |x| x.firstname }
```

This is also equivalent to:

```
firstname = :firstname.to_proc
@partner.employees.map(&firstname)
```

You can pass any proc or lambda in there using the same notation--

```
@partner.employees.map(&lambda { |x| "#{x.firstname} #{x.lastname}" })
```

Which is of course a bit pointless when you can use conventional block notation:

```
@partner.employees.map { |x| "#{x.firstname} #{x.lastname}" }.join(', ')
```

(But it's good to know anyway.)